# Update attachment metadata fails

Tags: ajax, attachments, post-meta

Updating attachment title and description metadata with `wp_ajax` breaks all previous datas and structure of attachment, my php code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_attachment', 'update_attachment_callback' );
function update_attachment_callback() {
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : FALSE;
    $title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'TITLE';
    $description = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : 'Description';
    if($id){
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($id, array(
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description
        ));
    }
    echo 'ok';
    wp_die();
}
```

And payload: with JS

```
data = {
    'action': 'update_attachment',
    'title' : title,
    'id': id,
    'description': description
};
```

Everything fine but, once it update the attachement data, i loose lots of attachment datas such as `width`, `height`, `sizes.thumbnail` etc...

I have no idea why this data are loosing, because im not changing any of these datas, i only updates `title` and `description` of attachament.

This is before update of attachment (from js console).
[image: before updating]

Same attachment just after update.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update `title` and `description` you should not use `wp_update_attachment_metadata` attachment title and description is not a meta it's a main post detail (attachment is custom post), you can do this with following code.

```
$attachment = array(
  'ID' => $id,
  'post_title' => $title,
  'post_content' => $description
);
// now update main post body
wp_update_post( $attachment );
```